# Merge two dictionaries by key but keep both values

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, merge

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
Dim dict1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dict1.Add("first","A")
dict1.Add("third","C")
dict1.Add("fifth","E")
dict1.Add("sixth","F")

Dim dict2 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dict2.Add("first","AA")
dict2.Add("second","BB")
dict2.Add("fourth","DD")
dict2.Add("sixth","FF")
```

I want to combine them into one master list by key, retaining both values. My final result would be in the format:

```
Dim combined As Dictionary(Of String, List(of String))
```

And based on the example above, would look something like:

```
{
    "first" : ["A", "AA"],
    "second" : ["", "BB"],
    "third" : ["C", ""],
    "fourth" : ["", "DD"],
    "fifth" : ["E", ""],
    "sixth" : ["F", "FF"]
}
```

Notice that every key from both lists carries over to the new, combined list. If the key has a value in both locations, both values are put into the list. If the key has a value in only one of the two locations, the value is placed in the corresponding first or second position with an empty string in the other.

How could I merge them in this manner?

Comment: The `List(Of String)` piece in the `combined` declaration could be an array instead of a list, I suppose. But that isn't really the point of the question.

Comment: Are you looking for a svelte one-liner? Or are you okay with a two-pass approach?

Comment: @Forty3 - I'm fine with whatever approach works. If it takes a couple passes, that's alright.

Comment: Using a dictionary for your list of keys wont work if you have multiple keys that are empty strings. You'll need to user either a tuple as @Ctznkane525 suggests, or a list. Personally I would suggest using a list if you have a varying number of values for each key.

Comment: @DavidWilson - There won't be any keys that are empty strings and there will always be a maximum of 2 values, one from dict1 and one from dict2.

Comment: Tuple it is then :-) If you decide to choose the advice from @Ctznkane525 , don't for get to tick it :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a Tuple(Of String, String).  Item1 will be the first one and Item2 will be the second dictionary.  Since you know the list would be exactly two, you might as well do it this way instead.

```
Dim combined As New Dictionary(Of String, Tuple(Of String, String))
For Each key as String in dict1.Keys.Union(dict2.Keys)

    Dim value1 as String = "" : dict1.TryGetValue(key, value1)
    Dim value2 as String = "" : dict2.TryGetValue(key, value2)
    combined.Add(key, new Tuple(Of String, String)(value1, value2))
Next
```

If you want the list, the question will be if you want the elements if they don't exist.

```
Dim combined As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
For Each key as String in dict1.Keys.Union(dict2.Keys)

    Dim value1 as String = ""
    Dim keyAdded as Boolean = False
    Dim keyList as new List(Of String)
    If dict1.TryGetValue(key, value1) Then 
      keyList.Add(value1)
    End If
    Dim value2 as String = ""
    If dict2.TryGetValue(key, value2) Then
        keyList.Add(value2)
    End If
    combined.Add(key, keyList)
Next
```

Comment: Nice use of the `.Keys.Union(...)`. However, this will create a jagged `List(Of String)` for keys not shared between the two original `Dictionary(Of String, String)`.

Comment: I prefer the  tuple method

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, there will be some `List(Of String)` values in the final `Dictionary` that only have a single entry vs. an empty entry when one of the source `Dictionary` items lacks the key. Indeed, the `Tuple` method is cleaner when there is a known, fixed number of source `Dictionary` items.